# Identification of a badge with Russian text

Tags: soviet-union, russia, identification

Here's a curious badge that I found somewhere years ago, but didn't know whom to ask.

[image: russian badge]
[image: backside of badge] (click to enlarge)

Could someone please identify it? I learnt the Cyrillic script and tried googling it, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The text reads АРХАНГЕЛЬСК ПАМЯТНИК ПЕТРУ I.
which translates as "Archangelsk – Monument to Peter I."
<sub>(kudos for translation refinement to @Neith)</sub>

A similar medal is on ebay as:

> [image] <sub>(click images for larger versions)</sub>
>   [Commemorative Soviet medal “Arkhangelsk 1584 ”/ Peter the Great](https://www.ebay.ca/itm/Commemorative-Soviet-medal-Arkhangelsk-1584-Peter-the-Great/273842384854)

Note that the city of [Archangelsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arkhangelsk) was founded in 1584 under a different name but owes a lot of its importance to [Peter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_the_Great).

The same iconic picture fo Peter [is used here:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Banknote_500_rubles_2010_front.jpg)

> [image: Banknote 500 rubles 2010 front]

and it's based on [this statue](http://wikimapia.org/1581510/Statue-of-Peter-the-Great) in the city at [Severnoy Dviny Embankment | Voskresenskaya St., Arkhangelsk](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g298499-d6474696-Reviews-Peter_The_Great_Monument-Arkhangelsk_Arkhangelsk_Oblast_Northwestern_District.html), Russia

> [image]
>   [Памятник Петру I в Архангельске](https://m.sputnik-georgia.ru/spravka/20170531/236171694/Den-severnogo-flota-VMF-Rossii-2017-istorija-i-tradicii-flota.html)

The [text again](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%A5%D0%90%D0%9D%D0%93%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%A1%D0%9A%20%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%9C%D0%AF%D0%A2%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%9A%20%D0%9F%D0%95%D0%A2%D0%A0%D0%A3%20I.) leads us to the Russian Wikipedia page of [Памятник Петру I (Архангельск)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83_I_(%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA))

---

**Dating it**

On an unreferenceable hunch I thought that the style would point to Soviet times. This pre-1991 date seems to be more probable if we look at the backside.  As @Rompey draw attention in comments

> on the back face of the badge is its price--10 copecks. You could buy ten boxes of matches for it or take two bus-rides in the Soviet Union.

As the price for this badge is listed *in the metal*, that is at the time of manufacturing not likely to change anytime soon, and that being a somewhat widespread practice in socialist countries, it seems ever more likely that another comment presents a more focussed date:

> Most likely, this was manufactured in 1984, on the 400th anniversary of Archangelsk. Similar badges were made on other similar anniversaries.
>   <sub>@vpekar</sub>

<sub>(Better dating still possible. If you know something, write something ;)</sub>

Comment: Alright, that's settled then. Thanks for the surprisingly fast answer!

Comment: You're new here; this is just normal behavior for @langlangc.

Comment: “In remembrance of” would be “в память о”. The text on the badge is clearly two separate phrases: “Arkhangelsk” and “Monument to Peter I”.

Comment: The badge is actually very small(2 cm in diameter). What could the purpose of the badge be(military/costume/?) and how did it end up in India? Is it possible to comment on that?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer The exact badge is probably a souvenir, a travel trophy, sold at the museum? So a traveler (from Russia or from India, or…)  might have transported it. Then there are collectors of these things. Garage sales and flea markets and the net. Hard to tell. –– But where does the info on India come from? That's not in the question. If you have info on provenance of an object, all relevant info should be in the question. (Generally. In this case, I probably can't offer more then the conjectures in this comment)

Comment: You're right, "souvenir" makes sense. I was actually wondering how it ended up in my grandfather's purse(no one's ever been to Russia). I assumed he must have collected it on his trips to the neighbouring state of Kerala, so I half-thought there must have been some Russian presence there. And about India, I live there! Sorry about puzzling you like that. And thanks so much again.

Comment: By the way, on the back face of the badge is its price--10 copecks. You could buy ten boxes of matches for it or take two bus-rides in the Soviet Union.

Comment: @LangLangC Most likely, this was manufactured in 1984, on the 400th anniversary of Archangelsk. Similar badges were made on other similar anniversaries.

Comment: @LangLangC Here are a few examples: [50th anniversary](https://picclick.com/1981-Russian-VOLOGDA-Airport-50th-Anniversary-Badge-230740959288.html) of the Vologda airport, [50th anniversary](https://www.etsy.com/listing/574804070/ussr-soviet-union-medal-1982) of the Magnitogorsk Metallurgy Factory, [300th anniversary](https://www.etsy.com/uk/listing/488393828/rare-badge-vintage-ussr-300-anniversary?ga_order=most_relevant&ga_search_type=all&ga_view_type=gallery&ga_search_query=ussr+rare+badge&ref=sr_gallery-1-17&referring_page_type=market&pro=1) of the re-unification of Russia and Ukraine, etc.

Comment: [This](https://www.nytimes.com/1974/09/22/archives/pin-hobby-soviet-fad-is-criticized-millions-to-be-produced-badges.html) article in NYT talks about this very topic: "The Soviet practice of marking anniversaries of all sorts gave birth to wave upon wave of znachki — for the liberation of Kiev from the Nazis, for the construction of the Bratsk dam and for various space exploits."

Comment: Google images “значок Архангельск памятник Петру” and you’ll find this badge and lots of similar ones listed on some Russian online flea markets. It costs 20-50 rubles, less than a dollar.